# Siamese Neural Network in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I implement a siamese neural network in PyTorch?

> **What is a siamese neural network?** A siamese neural network consists in two *identical* neural networks, each one taking one input. *Identical* means that the two neural networks have the exact same architecture and share the same weights.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implementing siamese neural networks in PyTorch is as simple as calling the network function twice on different inputs.

```
mynet = torch.nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(10, 512),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(512, 2))
...
output1 = mynet(input1)
output2 = mynet(input2)
...
loss.backward()
```

When invoking `loss.backwad()`, PyTorch will automatically sum the gradients coming from the two invocations of `mynet`.

You can find a full-fledged example [here](https://github.com/benmyara/pytorch-examples/blob/master/notebooks/1_NeuralNetworks/9_siamese_nn.ipynb).

Comment: Why is the loss function CrossEntropyLoss? I thought it was supposed to be contrastive or triplet loss...

Comment: You can use many types of losses with siamese networks. Binary cross entropy can be used for binary classification tasks, which is exactly the task being solved by a siamese network (`same class` vs. `different class`). Triplet loss, vanilla hinge loss, etc. can also be used. Because siamese networks are often used to create strongly discriminative embeddings, losses such as the triplet loss or the hinge loss –which put emphasis on imposing margins between embeddings of different classes– are indeed quite common in this context. But the cross entropy loss is also a valid choice.

Comment: I read, "Since training of Siamese networks involves pairwise learning, Cross entropy loss cannot be used in this case." This must be flat out incorrect?
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-friendly-introduction-to-siamese-networks-85ab17522942